# How is a change saved to an encrypted file on a cloud storage service?

Tags: encryption, save, cloud, google-cloud-storage

If I am using a cloud storage service which uses client-side encryption so that the server could never in theory access my unencrypted files, how would the server save a file change?  For instance, if I make only a small addition to a 2.5 GB video file, would the cloud server have to re-upload the entire 2.5 GB file?  Or is it possible for a server to only update the changed parts even though it can't "see" what the changed parts are due to the encryption?

I am having a bit of a logical crisis here; thank you anyone who can help!

Comment: Practically speaking, you should use some diff based synchronization tool/library like rsync, but I don't know if  GCS supports it and whether there is client implementation.

Comment: Diff-based synchronization wouldn't be possible if the data are encrypted client-side, since the service would be unable to decrypt the content and apply the diff.

Comment: I read a bit more about standard encryption schemes like AES and indeed it seems there would be no alternative to re-uploading the whole file since a small change could affect the whole binary :( alas, I guess some problems are unavoidable

Answer (score 0):

If you're encrypting client-side you would have to re-upload the entire file if you change any part of it.